# How to change Google Cloud instance type using Python update method

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-instances

Using Python example [from docs on `insert` method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert)

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)


project = 'my-project' 
zone = 'us-west1-a' 
instance_body = {
    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
}

request = service.instances().update(project=project, zone=zone, body=instance_body)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

I customize the `instance_body`  variable to be

```
instance_body = {
    'name': 'my-vm-0001',
    'machineType':  'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%s/zones/%s/machineTypes/e2-highcpu-32' % (project, zone)
}
```

But running the `update()` method

```
request = service.instances().update(project=project, zone=zone, body=instance_body)
response = request.execute()
```

raises `TypeError: Missing required parameter "instance"`.

Is there a way to update the instance type using the `update` method? It appears changing the instancy type can be done using `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud compute instances set-machine-type my-vm-0001 --project my-project --zone=us-west1-a--machine-type=e2-highcpu-32
```

Comment: You are missing the **instance** parameter:  `service.instances().update(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instanceName, body=instance_body)`. `gcloud compute instances list` will provide you with the instance name.

Comment: Python docs: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instances.html#update More information on updating instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/update-instance-properties#api

Comment: This could be posted as the answer.

Comment: The `instance_body` dictionary is expected to contain the required keys-values defined. Please post your opinions as the answers. Appending an additional parameter `instance=instanceName` doesn't help to make this snippet work.

Comment: I posted as a comment because I did not verify my comment. I know the API well and knew the issue with the missing parameter. After adding the parameter `instance`, what is the error message now.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method takes the same parameters defined in the `instance_body` variable as the `insert` method with an additional `fingerprint` one which should match the fingerprint of the instance that you can query by instance name.

Comment: Can you post the changes you made to the code that solved your problem?